# Why aren't my Firebase Storage photos loading into a UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uicollectionview, firebase-storage

I am using a `UICollectionView` in my iOS app to allow users to view their photos in a grid view. Their photos are stored in Firebase Storage and they should be fetched down and displayed in the `UICollectionView`. However, I am not sure how I should do this. I searched the internet but cannot find any quality tutorials on how to successfully complete this. I have also searched Stack Overflow and was unable to find any questions besides [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45662637/unable-to-display-firebase-storage-images-into-a-collectionview-swift), however, it has no answers. Here's a walkthrough of my current code:

This is the function used to upload the images to Firebase Storage. `uploadImage(imageData: )` accepts a `Data` object that is retrieved via a `UIImagePickerController`. This function is working perfectly fine:

```
func uploadImage(imageData: Data) {
    let imageID = UUID().uuidString
    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(withPath: "\(partyID)_photo_sharing_images/\(imageID).jpg")
    let metadata = StorageMetadata()
    metadata.contentType = "image/jpeg"

    storageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: metadata) { (metadata, err) in
        if let err = err {
           self.showAlertWithOK(title: "An Error Occurred", message: "Something went wrong while uploading your image.")
               print("An error occurred: \(err)")
           }

           storageRef.downloadURL { (url, err) in
              if let err = err {
                  print("An error occurred: \(err.localizedDescription)")
              }

              guard let url = url else { return }
              self.uploadImageData(url: url.absoluteString)
          }
     }
}
```

Once the image is uploaded to Firebase Storage, I use the function `uploadImageData(url: )` to upload the image URL to Google Cloud Firestore. After that, I have begun to struggle with my code.

I have created a custom object named Photo that as three different values:  a `URL`, a `String`, and an `Int`. I have an array of `Photo` objects and I read from the array to download the images from Firebase Storage into the `UICollectionViewCell`. Here is the code that does that:

```
func loadImagesData() {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let partyRef = db.collection("parties").document(partyID)

    partyRef.addSnapshotListener() { (snapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
           print("An error occurred: \(err.localizedDescription)")
           self.showAlertWithOK(title: "An Error Occurred", message: err.localizedDescription)
        } else {
           let photoSharingImages = snapshot?.data()?["photo_sharing_images"] as? [String] ?? [String]()

           for photoSharingImage in photoSharingImages {
               guard let url = URL(string: photoSharingImage) else {
               print("Unable to retrieve URL from photo sharing image URL.")
               return
           }

            let photo = Photo(photographer: "none", likes: 0, url: url)
            self.photos.append(photo)
         }

         print("These are the URL from the array: \(photoSharingImages)")
     } 
}
```

`loadImagesData()` grabs the image download URLs from Firestore and adds them to a `Photo`. That new `Photo` then gets appended to the `photos` array.
Next, the `photos` need to be added to the `UICollectionView` using the download URLs fetched from Firestore. I am currently using a function called `loadImage()` which loads the image from Storage and loads it into memory. Here is the function I have create for that.

```
func loadImage(photo: Photo) -> UIImage {
    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: photo.url.absoluteString)

    var image: UIImage?
    storageRef.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, err in
       if let err = err {
         print("An error occurred: \(err.localizedDescription)")
       } else {
         if let data = data {
           image = UIImage(data: data)
         }
       }
    }

    return image ?? UIImage()
}
```

I then call that function in `collectionView(_ collectionView:, cellForItemAt indexPath: )` like so:

```
let photo = photos[indexPath.row]

// Configure the cell.
cell.photoImageView.image = loadImage(photo: photo)
```

However, the photos, unfortunately, are not being displayed in the `UICollectionViewCell`'s `UIImageView`. Why is this happening? How do I properly load the photos into the `UICollectionViewCell`'s `UIImageView` to fix this issue.

Comment: "I then call that function in collectionView(_ collectionView:, numberOfItemsInSection section: ) like so:" . Are you sure you're not making a mistake here? It doesn't make sense. Do you mean in `cellForItem` func?

Comment: @SoroushShahi I'm sorry, that was an error. I meant `cellForItem`.

Comment: And I can't see `collection.reloadData()` anywhere.

Comment: @SoroushShahi Yes, that is the problem. I do not know where to call that using the implementation I have right now. I would like to know if there is another way to load the images into the `UICollectionViewCell`.

Comment: You need to call it wherever your datasource gets updated. In your case, `photos` is your datasource. So call it right after `self.photos.append(photo)` and check if it works.

Comment: @SoroushShahi I actually decided to change the implementation. Instead of calling `loadImage()` in the collection view cell delegate function, I call it once I load each image. Also, I am storing the image in the `Photo` object instead.